# Binding doesn't update when the original object changes

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I think I have misunderstood something about how data-binding and scopes work in Angular, or maybe I have some misconception in Javascript in general. I hope somebody can help me.

Let's say I have a factory that has an object, and defines a getter/setter for it:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function(){

    var myObject : {

        subObject : {

             subProperty : 'value'
        }
    };

    return {

        getObject : function() {

            return myObject;
        },

        setObject : function(obj) {

            myObject = obj;
        }
    };
};
```

Then, in a controller I get this object and assign the subObject to the scope:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myFactory){

    var myObject = myFactory.getObject();

    $scope.subObject = myObject.subObject;
});
```

In the view, I bind to the subProperty of that object:

```
<div> {{subObject.subProperty}} </div>
```

Then, somebody calls the myFactoy.setObject() method and replaces the original object in the factory for a new one. 
Shouldn't my binding be updated automatically?? if it shouldn't... which is the best way to accomplish this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original object doesn't change. You're just changing the reference to it.

---

Use this instead:

```
setObject : function(obj) {

    angular.copy(obj, myObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks, my actual code was a bit more complicated, but this pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Yes! I was just about to give up