# Binding doesn't update when the original object changes. Is copying the only/best solution?

Tags: angularjs

I'm running into the same problem as stated here.

[Binding doesn't update when the original object changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519698/binding-doesnt-update-when-the-original-object-changes/32214521#32214521).

I'm looking for more opinions on how to approach this problem.

I would think this would be a very common problem. Pretty much all ajax request in spa's return json which is used to create js objects. New references are created to point to these objects and/or existing references are updated to point to these new objects.

Is copying the object properties from the new object to the existing object the only/best solution? What if the object is a big collection or has a deep graph? It seems like copying wouldn't work well. Is there a way to monitor/watch the reference?

Am I thinking about this wrong?

As request i've setup a jsfiddle to simulate the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/ho69ofog/

```
    var newObject = {
        "subObject": {
            "subProperty": Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5)
        }
    };
    myObject = newObject;
```

Notice that the only scope value that is updating is when the whole factory object attached to the scope. As mentioned above and in the referenced issue [Binding doesn't update when the original object changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519698/binding-doesnt-update-when-the-original-object-changes/32214521#32214521) , copying the object instead of creating a new object(inside the updateTimer function) will cause all scope values to update.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Show some code. there are lots of reasons bindings can be broken. Angular also has utilities like `angular.extend()` and `angular.merge()` that can help breaking references. There are also `diff` libraries you can use that run in webworkers

Comment: I've edited the issue and added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the only solution, but it's one of the simplest.
Here's another. Use a $watch in the controller to detect when the object has changed.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return myFactory.getObject();
},
function(newValue){
  $scope.subObject = angular.isDefined(newValue) ? newValue.subObject : undefined;
});
```

Comment: I've used this approach also and it works.  The main thing that I don't like about it is all of the controllers will need to watch the service's data object.  It seems like a lot of clutter in the controllers.

Comment: In that case another option is to fire an event from the factory whenever the data changes (`$rootScope.$emit('dataChanged', newData);`).
You'd still have to listen to that event in all the controllers, but it would be more efficient than many $watches.
If you want to do this without any code in the controller, then `angular.copy` or `angular.extend` etc are the best options.